# Can I transfer my hotel reservation?

Tags: hotels, cancellations

I booked a hotel for a conference visit in Barcelona. Although I have the appropriate visa for Spain, my passport is at the UK embassy due to a visa application that is taking much longer than the average processing time (3 weeks delay so far).

My question is, what can I do about my hotel booking in Barcelona if I cannot go? I booked it through booking.com, it is past the free cancellation date (I can cancel now but I'd pay 355 EUR), the hotel doesn't want to make an exception, and booking.com's customer service failed to convince the hotel to make an exception.

However, I can transfer the booking to someone else. Are there any websites or such that can help me find someone to transfer the booking to? I found transfertravel.com, but the problem is that they require that I had already *paid* for the booking.

Comment: I realized now that my question was not well framed. I updated it now.

Answer (score 7):

A Google search on *sell hotel reservation* returns several sites that resell nonrefundable hotel reservations, for a fee. Both say it coordinates with the hotel to change the booking name and credit card guarantee.

[**RoomerTravel**](https://www.roomertravel.com/cancellation/how_to_sell)

[**CancelOn**](https://www.cancelon.com/)